# exchange key and vals in a map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map with (xi,f(xi)) and my f(xi) are also strictly increasing. I need to exchange key and vals this way

input of my function :

a map with

```
//keys :  x0,       x1,     x2,     ...,        xn
// vals :  f(x_0)   f(x1),  f(x2),  ...,        f(xn)
```

output of my function : 
a map with

```
// key : left_val f(x_0)    f(x1),  ...,        f(xn-1)
// vals : x0,       x1,     x2,     ...,        xn
```

(here left_val is an input parameter, I know it is lower than f(x0)). 
I know I might not be using the right structure but I really need the log(n) insertion and uniqueness of ordered keys ...

How would you implement that efficiently (i.e. not duplicating the map) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want do do??

Comment: @Mario I changed the specification of input-ouput of my function. Is it clearer ?

Comment: You have given the 'left_val' and look for 'f(x_n) <= left_val < f(x_n1)' to get the x_n?

Comment: As an algorithmic problem or using Standard Library containers?

Comment: @DyP keeping all data into a map (or suggesting another container). I edit the question to clarify that

Comment: @robingirard: just a tiny remark: `std::map` does not guarantee uniqueness of `keys`. it guarantees uniqueness of the result of the cmp-function, the cmp-function is used to identify equal 'keys'. think of having `std::map<User*, int>` and use the `User::name()` to 'order' the map. even unique users (keys) are not allowed when then `name()` is equal ( `a->name() == b->name()`, `a != b`)

Comment: @akira thanks you'r right I was unexact. I might remove that from the question ?

Comment: @robingirard: no, let it there. it has educational value for others. i was just reminded of how i stumbled once upon this little detail.

Comment: If you can't establish a bidirectional relation while building the map (<->boost::bimap), IIRC you're stuck with O(n*logn) speed. You don't have any influence on the internal allocations of `std::map` besides the allocator, so there's no way change a key (erase the element and insert a new one).

Comment: @DyP: You can build a new map in O(n) time if the elements are already ordered (as they are here) and you provide hints to `insert` that each should go at the end.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You're right, I originally misunderstood the OP - thinking the order of `f` and `x` was different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an unusual situation in that you're wanting to change the `std::map` keys, which is normally forbidden to avoid changes that would break the ordering.  If you're confident to ensure this invariant yourself, then you can modify the `std::map` as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    typedef std::map<double, double> Mdd;

    Mdd m;
    m[1] = 4;
    m[2] = 6.5;
    m[3] = 7.2;
    m[4] = 9.3;
    m[5] = 12;

    double x = 2.3;

    for (Mdd::iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i)
    {
        double old_second = i->second;
        i->second = i->first;
        const_cast<double&>(i->first) = x;
        x = old_second;
    }

    for (Mdd::const_iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << i->first << "->" << i->second << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2.3->1
4->2
6.5->3
7.2->4
9.3->5
```

All this does is use `const_cast` to insist on write access to the key.  Strictly speaking, I suspect the Standard wouldn't require an implementation to work after such hackery, but in practice I can't imagine an implementation that wouldn't.  You will need to decide what you want to do with the final value of `x` - in your question that'd be `f(xn)`... I've discarded it as suggested by your question.

In terms of efficiency, this does a single in-order pass over the `map`, which is unavoidable if wishing to use such a container.  There is no copying of the map or additional heap allocations.  After the transformation, and subject to the caveat above about support not being guaranteed by the Standard, you can expect to have a "normal" valid map in which it's safe to insert and remove elements.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted. Tricky. This also can be used to answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743545/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-change-a-key-of-an-element-inside-stdmap ?

Comment: @robingirard: good that it helped :-).  Regarding the linked question, this approach could be used but the keys and values between the old and new in-order location of the keys would need to be changed: that's nice if the new key is in about the same place in the ordering, but if the nodes are more than a few elements apart I'd expect it to become slower than the `erase`/`insert` alternative (exact threshold depends on new/delete and key/value copy performance etc.).  What the question is asking for is to have two log2N lookups and leave the intervening nodes untouched: more generally useful.

Answer (score 1):

When inserting a new entry into the new map, use the [binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to do the insertion. Each insertion will be O(log n), and the total time to recreate the map should be O(n log n).

Comment: Why would you need a binary search if the entries are already sorted? Insert them in order, with a hint that they should be at the end, and you'll get linear complexity. And why would use use a binary search with a map anyway? It orders the elements automatically.

Comment: From the question I thought that the problem was implementing a custom map that puts the elements in a table in stictly increasing order by key. The O(log n) time caused me to think of binary search, but you are correct that this would not apply to this case where f(xi) is also strictly increasing.