# Modify key of std::map

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a way to modify the key of a `std::map` or ? [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743545/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-change-a-key-of-an-element-inside-stdmap) shows how to do so with rebalancing the tree. But what if I provide some guarantees that the key won't need to be rebalanced?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


class Keymap
{
private:    
    int key; // this key will be used for the indexing
    int total;
public:
    Keymap(int key): key(key), total(0)
    {}
    bool operator<(const Keymap& rhs) const{
        return key < rhs.key;
    }
    void inc()
    {
        total++;
    }
};
std::map<Keymap, int> my_index;



int main (){
    std::map<Keymap, int> my_index;
    Keymap k(2);
    my_index.insert(std::make_pair(k, 0));

    auto it = my_index.begin();

    it->first.inc(); // this won't rebalance the tree from my understanding
    return 0;
}
```

The modification won't compile because of the constness of `it->first`

Is there any way to override this behavior?

Comment: Can you give a practical example where it matters?

Comment: Are you tied to the container type `std::map<Keymap, int>`, or can you instead use something like `struct Value { int total; int index; }; std::map<int, Value>`?

Comment: @bobah You can have situations where you want to map between objects where the key has more functionality than being a literal map key, or a set with similar properties. More precisely, it could definitely have other members that do not affect its sorting order and that should be modifiable. Say, you get a `std::set<Cars, SortByLicensePlate> carsToInspect;` where you want to change the inspection date after processing them. You could (and possibly should) use a `std::vector` here instead, but you get the point.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - all such use cases are design flaws. In your example it should either be `std::map<CarLicensePlate, Car>` or something similar to the `boost::multi_index` which, being an indexing container, has consistent support of data modification.

Comment: @bobah you have a valid point that this can be viewed as design flaw. However what you proposing you either have to move `CarLicensePlate` out of the `Car` class or have a duplicate field which is memory inefficient. So it all comes down how the key relates to the object. But I get your point it is hard to make a case with this one. In my case, I wanted to avoid the cost of refactoring to store some metadata.

Comment: @MiniFridge - understood. Regarding the data duplication - most strings used as keys can be cheated with and stored in a uint64_t or uint128_t sized POD, referring to them would be the same as copying them. Additionally string keys can be "interned" as integers and stopped at the perimeter. But these are better done when writing from scratch, not with legacy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make `inc` const and `total` mutable

```
class Keymap
{
private:    
    int key; // this key will be used for the indexing
    mutable int total;
public:
    Keymap(int key): key(key), total(0)
    {}
    bool operator<(const Keymap& rhs) const{
        return key < rhs.key;
    }
    void inc() const
    {
        total++;
    }
};
```

But you do need to ask yourself why you are doing this, `mutable` isn't used much.

You're right that no rebalancing is going to happen.

Comment: "isn't used much" is not a reason to ask yourself why you are doing this. `mutable` has its uses and necessities. The present case is actually a valid use case for `mutable`, although one might argue it allows too much modification.

Comment: How can you determine that this a valid use case for `mutable`? We are not seeing how `total` is used and whether it has any externally observable effect (it _currently_ doesn't, but it also serves no purpose whatsoever, so the example is clearly incomplete). You would need to make a very good case to use `mutable`, not just "it helps here"...

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot change the design and introduce surrogate read-only keys, your best option is to use [Boost.MultiIndex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) container (I am not aware of reasonable alternatives). It is designed specifically for this purpose and has consistent built-in support of updating the indexed object, including the transactional variant. Documentation and code examples are [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#ord_updating).

Generally, patterns like storing business entities in a self-keyed sets, having mutable keys serving additional purpose (counters and whatnot), etc. tend to have impact on maintenability, performance, and scalability of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your keys into a class that allows modification of const objects. One such class would be `std::unique_ptr`:

```
using KeymapPtr = std::unique_ptr<Keymap>;

struct PtrComp
{
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(const std::unique_ptr<T>& lhs, const std::unique_ptr<T>& rhs) const
    {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};

template<class V>
using PtrMap = std::map<KeymapPtr, V, PtrComp>;

int main (){
    PtrMap<int> my_index;
    KeymapPtr k = std::make_unique<Keymap>(2);
    my_index.emplace(std::move(k), 0);

    auto it = my_index.begin();

    it->first->inc(); // this won't rebalance the tree from my understanding
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/65vhck)

Note that we have to supply a custom comparator object since we (presumably) want to sort by the key values, not the pointer values.

To be clear, this is not what `unique_ptr` is meant for, and the `const` semantics of smart pointers (which follow those of regular pointers) are a bit backwards from this perspective (why can I get a non-`const` reference from a `const` object? A linter may complain about this kind of use...), but it does the trick here. The same would of course work with naked pointers (where a `T* const` can have the `T` value changed but not the pointer location, whereas a `const T*` can have its location changed but not the `T`), but this mimics the ownership/lifetime model of your original code.

Needless to say, this opens the door to breaking the map invariants (breaking the sortedness by keys) so think twice before using it. But unlike `const_cast`ing your key directly, it is free of UB.

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` and the other standard associative containers do not provide a way to do this without removing and adding an element, likely causing tree rebalancing side effects.  You can go around the map key constness in various ways (e.g. using `mutable` members), but then it's entirely up to you to make sure you don't actually break the key ordering.

If you need this sort of efficiency but a bit more safety, you might consider changing the container to a [`boost::multi_index_container`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) instead.

A `std::map<K,V>` is similar to:

```
namespace BMI = boost::multi_index;
using map_value_type = std::pair<K, V>;
using map_type = BMI::multi_index_container<
    map_value_type,
    BMI::indexed_by<BMI::ordered_unique<
        BMI::member<map_value_type, &map_value_type::first>
>>>;
```

except that in a `multi_index_container`, the entire element is always `const`.  If you want to be able to directly modify the `second` members, a means for that is described on [this boost page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/techniques.html#emulate_assoc_containers).

`multi_index_container` provides two members the standard associative containers do not, [`replace` and `modify`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#ord_updating).  Both of these will check for whether the modified element is in the same sort order or not.  If it is, no rebalancing is done.

```
auto it = my_index.begin();
auto pair = *it;
pair.first.inc();
my_index.replace(it, pair);

// OR

auto it = my_index.begin();
my_index.modify(it, [](auto& pair) { pair.first.inc(); });
```